# Spring boot JPA BaseEntity with unique id to each class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have an abstract class BaseEntity which contains fields I want to share with multiple objects inside my project.

```
    @MappedSuperclass
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Data
    public abstract class BaseEntity {
    
        @Id
        @Column(name = "objectId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
        private long objectId;
    
        @Column(name = "createdDate", updatable = false/*, columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"*/)
        @CreationTimestamp
        private Date createdDate;
    
        @Column(name = "updatedDate"/*, columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"*/)
        @UpdateTimestamp
        private Date updatedDate;
    
        @Column(name = "active", columnDefinition = "boolean default false")
        private boolean active;
}
```

I've multiple entities that are inherited from this class

For my example let's take two of them:

1. User
2. Contact

While saving a `User` object on the DB I can see the `objectId` field is getting incremented, but as well for another object such as `Contact`

For example:

I created an instance of User and saved it on DB, After persisting I can see my `User.objectId = 1`.

After that I created an instance of Contact and saved it on DB, After persisting I can see my `Contact.objectId = 2`

How can I make the field `objectId` increment separately for each Entity?

Thanks.

Comment: `GenerationType.AUTO` leaves it up to the JPA implementation (I assume Hibernate) to choose a generation strategy. Hibernate bases that choice on the DB dialect you're using. What is your dialect (which RDBMS and version)?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say whether you're using Hibernate as the JPA implementation, but since that's by far the most common choice, I'll answer based on it.

When you specify `GenerationType.AUTO` as the strategy for an `@GeneratedValue` identifier, the persistence provider (Hibernate) is left to choose the strategy. Hibernate uses `SEQUENCE` as its default choice* (unless you configure it otherwise), and that default behavior of `SEQUENCE` is to use a single, shared, DB sequence for all Hibernate-managed entities. That's why you're seeing the IDs increment across all entities/tables instead of each table's IDs be independent.

If you want to continue using sequence-based ID generation, it's possible to specify a sequence name for each entity, [example here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-sequence-named). That way, each entity type (table) can have an independent sequence of IDs. Note that if you have lots of entities/tables, this approach will produce a separate DB sequence for each one, which might not be ideal.

Another straightforward way to get what you're looking for would be to change the `GenerationType` to `IDENTITY`.

**PLEASE NOTE**: there are other options and lots of considerations (such as performance and support for batch inserts) when deciding on the ID generation strategy. I strongly urge you to read the Hibernate documentation, [starting here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators), to fully understand the options and make an informed choice for your specific situation.

---

*This is not exactly true for MySQL since MySQL doesn't seem to natively support sequences. For MySQL, Hibernate will fall back to using the `TABLE` strategy, as [described here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.6/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#identifiers-generators-auto:%7E:text=It%20is%20important%20to,transparent%20to%20the%20user.).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a different sequence for each concrete class, the @Id and @GeneratedValue annotations - and thus the PK field - should be in the concrete class not in the root abstract one.